# Best way to group elements in a list of lists

Tags: c++, list, oop

I have 4 lists of sorted data.

```
std::vector<A> aList;
std::vector<B> bList;
std::vector<C> cList;
std::vector<D> dList;
```

I want to find unique value combinations for aList and bList.
eg.

```
aList = {1,1,2,2,2}
bList = {a,b,a,a,a}
cList = {c1,c2,c3,c4,c5}
dList = {d1,d2,d3,d4,d5}
```

expected output

```
{c1,d1},
{c2,d2},
{{c3,d3},{c4,d4},{c5,d5}}
```

I had tried an approach with std::map using aList and BList 'value pair' as keys to get the result.
This works fine, but the code looks complicated.

Is it possible to achieve the same using class(OOPS)?
Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks in advance,

Vijay

Comment: Fear I don't understand what you mean by the data you gave. Are c1, d1 etc. placeholders for actual numbers/values? What happened to the 1, 2, a and b from your input data? Perhaps your complicated but working code would be helpful.

Comment: I also don't understand what you mean with _" to achieve the same using class"_? A `std::map` is a class, or what do you mean?

Comment: @churill I think he wants to "hide" the complexity behind a self-made class

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Good idea, sounds plausible. That would be the easiest part.

Comment: @ AlexGeorg  all the values mentioned are place holders(a,b,c,d).
I require to get a list of lists containing only matching cList and dList values.
aList and bList are to be used only to compute the output.

@ RoQuOTriX, @churill , You are right, I want to encapsulate this information in a class.

Comment: I was using an std::map to achieve this, an std::pair of aList and bList values was the 'key' and 'value' was a list of matching cList and dList values.

Comment: I'm still confused why some of those values should belong together or not. It would really help to see a small example without placeholders, or a clarification on the rules.

Comment: I have 4 lists. These lists contain information about some 3dmodels.

aList - List of color of objects(RGB value)
bList - List of transparency of objects(0-1)
cList - List of objects itself
dList - List of position of objects

I want to group all objects of the same color and transparency value along with its position

Answer (score 0):

Alright, with your info from the comment, that makes some more sense.

> I have 4 lists. These lists contain information about some 3dmodels.
>   aList - List of color of objects(RGB value) bList - List of
>   transparency of objects(0-1) cList - List of objects itself dList -
>   List of position of objects I want to group all objects of the same
>   color and transparency value along with its position –

Indeed this sounds like a task predestined to solve via OOP. Working with separate lists is not descriptive and can become confusing quickly.

First make a class like "`DetailedObject`" which has a member for whatever you call "object" till now (3D mesh?), the position and a member of another class I'd call "`AlphaColor`".
"`AlphaColor`" has the members "color" and "transparency" as you want to group by unique combinations of color and transparency, right?

Now you can make a result datastructure like this:

```
std::map<AlphaColor, std::vector<DetailedObject>>
```

You will notice that this won't compile before you haven't implemented a Hash function for AlphaColor (because the map needs that). You should find instructions for that online though.

Once you have that, the last thing you need to do is to loop through all your `DetailedObject` and simply insert them into the corresponding std::vector within the map by using their `AlphaColor` member as the key for the map.

EDIT: By the way, instead of a custom AlphaColor you might find some ready "RGBA" data type as that is a common use case in many libraries that do something with graphics.